# Exception when accessing Globals.ThisAddIn.Application in VSTO AddIn

Tags: c#, vsto, excel-addins

I am trying to create a MS Office VSTO AddIn using C#.
The AddIn contains a Ribbon that i added via the Ribbon-Designer in VS19.

I left the ThisAddin.cs file untouched:

```
namespace MyAddIn
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {

        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        #region VSTO generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

In the ribbon I added a button and wrote some code to be executed when clicked:

```
namespace MyAddIn
{
    public partial class my_ribbon
    {
        private void my_ribbon_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btn_myButton_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ThisWorkbook.FullName);
        }
    }
}
```

However, whenever I click on the button, C# throws me the following exception:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
  HResult=0x800A03EC
  Message=Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>
```

While debugging I saw, that `Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application` threw the error.
I found out that `0x800A03EC` is the error code for Name-Not-Found (according to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/82c70345-6e26-4dd8-925e-961d8729a3b5/exception-on-thisworkbook)).
But as I click the button once the file is opened, there should be an application object along with a full name.

I also took a look at [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-tab-by-using-the-ribbon-designer?view=vs-2019) but that didn't help much because they also use `Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application` but successfully.

Do you have any advice on how to fix this? (Any more initialization code needed, etc?)

Comment: Do you define `Application.ThisWorkbook` anywhere? `ThisWorkbook` looks like code for a  *document-level* customization, rather than an applicaiton-level add-in. If you substitute `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Workbook[1].FullName;` do you get a different result?

Comment: @CindyMeister I have a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61149776/1232087) regarding `Ribbon XML` control. I saw your response to a similar post [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/451878d6-1af3-4c40-9901-d8fe600f0ca9/how-can-i-access-a-created-ribbon-from-other-parts-of-my-application?forum=vsto) but was unable to implement it for `Ribbon XML` case. I was wondering if you would have time to comment/suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@Cindy Meister](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3077495/cindy-meister) pointed me in the right direction:

I am in fact writing an application-level add-in instead of a document-level customization and therefore don't have a `ThisWorkbook`. What I needed looking was `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook` (so the workbook instance where the click was invoked).

Replacing `ThisWorkbook` with `ActiveWorkbook` did the trick.